# How to add data from promise into MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, axios

I'm trying to add an array of json data from another server to a mongoDB collection, however I receive the this error message: "Cannot create property '_id' on string". However an array is passed in? I've tried parsing the JSON response however nothing works. Here's the code:

```
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

const axios = require('axios').default;



axios.get('http://arweave.net/peers')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        var dbo = db.db("mydb");
        dbo.collection("peerlist").insertMany(response.data, function(err, res) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Number of documents inserted: " + res.insertedCount);
            db.close();
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: So you did try `.insertMany(JSON.parse(response.data), ...`?

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, However it throws an unexpected token error. Isn't it already supposed to be valid json?

Comment: Apparently yes, axios seems to pre-parse it. So `response.data` should be an array. `.insertMany` expects an "array of documents", are you sure you can just use strings instead? You probably need something like `response.data.map(host => ({ host }));` so `"165.227.36.199:1984"` becomes `{ host: "165.227.36.199:1984" }` or whatever key it expects.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be an object. Since it is not (string array), mongo has no way to identify the name of the column. Change it to array of objects and it should be fine.

```
[{"someField": "someValue"}]
```